# Can this raw SQL be written using the Rails Active Record Query Interface? Should it be?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

In my Rails 4 app I make a fairly simple search for one of my models using the following SQL 'OR' statements. It works fine. Is there any way (and reason) to achieve this without raw SQL using the Rails Active Record Query Interface?

```
Activity.where("
    user_id = ? OR 
    category = ? OR 
    (secondary_id = ? AND secondary_model = ?) OR 
    (tertiary_id = ? AND tertiary_model = ?)",
    user_id, "Announcement", user_id, "user", user_id, "user"
).uniq
```

Comment: Might be able to use Arel, if that's still a thing

Comment: Have you tried the `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` ? It should solve your problem.

Comment: You can do it through AREL but I don't think it will be easier to read. Switching to named parameters (`user_id = :user_id or ...` with a Hash for the parameters) would be a good idea though, that will avoid duplicate parameters and order sensitivity in the parameter list.

Comment: It might be worth adding a `group` clause too to make the uniqueness the job of the db

Comment: @Pavling: `uniq` is an ActiveRecord method. GROUP BY is for aggregation, not uniqueness, using it for uniqueness is an abuse that only works with some databases.

Comment: How on earth have I missed that `uniq` adds `DISTINCT` (since 3.2 by the looks of it...)?! Assumed it was `Array.uniq`. Cool. Learn something every day! :-)

Comment: But distinct entire rows? If there's not unique keys on every field, that could end up with performance fun.

Comment: One of the advertised features of Active Record in Rails 5 is the addition of an `.or()` method. Currently, Active Record does not have an `.or()` method. There are, of course, many different workarounds (such as writing the SQL fragment like you are), but if you're looking for a clean solution, I don't think there is one. You can read about the Rails 5 `.or()` announcement here: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16052

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) here.  Many rails queries use Arel behind the scenes, but you can hook into it directly.

As to whether you should, I think it would depend on the project. We use Arel generally so that if we ever change our RDBM, it will take care of converting the SQL for us. I don't think it really makes it look much better.

Your code would look something like this

```
activities = Activity.arel_table
activities
   .where(activities[:user_id].eq(user_id)
   .or(activities[:category].eq("Announcement")
   .or((activities[:secondary_id].eq("user").and(activities[:secondary_model].eq(user_id))
   .or((activities[:tertiary_id].eq("user").and(activities[:secondary_model].eq(user_id)))
```

Comment: I find most AREL to be an incomprehensible mess. I don't understand the portability aspect, the hard parts of portability aren't really covered by AREL are they? To me, AREL is for programatically constructing things that standard AR calls aren't really up to. If the SQL is static then AREL just unnecessarily complicates things in the name of some sort of twisted sense of ideological purity. IMO of course.

Comment: I'm fairly new to it, so I don't have a strong opinion yet. I do agree that in this case, portability is not really an issue.